# How Elastic Fabric Adapter bypasses the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, rdma, infiniband

In this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/efa.html): it says "EFAs provide all of the same traditional IP networking features as ENAs, and they also support OS-bypass capabilities."

In technical terms how is this achieved? IOCTLs? something else?

I am reading the Linux kernel code for the EFA driver ([here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/infiniband/hw/efa)) and I am finding nothing that indicates how.

Anyone knows?